# jsf2 facelets: shouldnt be it enough to declare utf-8 in template?

Tags: jsf-2, encoding, utf-8, facelets

H i

i have a question, if i define my template as a UTF-8 page, shouldn't that behaviour be applied to all includes that invoke it?

i created a simple template, which prints "a ñu is a gnu  (this one works)", meaning that it can understand and properly handled the 'ñ' character. However, when i include another page (chupacabra), if i try to print a word containing the same 'ñ' character i get an com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:invalid byte

**simple_template.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >

    <h:head> 

    </h:head>
    <h:body style="background-color:black;" >
        a ñu is a gnu  (this one works)
        <ui:insert name="contenido"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**chupacabra.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition 
   template="/paginas/comun/simple_template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:dabit="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"> 
            <ui:define name="contenido">
<h:form>
    añoo (this one wont work)

    </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

Comment: Maybe it is just wrong encoding of your editor. If you are using eclipse open file properties and see encoding of **chupacabra.xhtml**

Comment: What editor are you using to edit/save Facelets files? Eclipse?

Comment: @partlov thanks partlov. rightclicked chupacabra.xhtml, properties, resource, set text file encoding as utf-8, closed eclipse, ran eclipse -clean, still getting the same exception.

Comment: Try to replace ñ with `&#xf1;`. If it works than it is editor, I'm sure.

Comment: thanks partlov, i made the changes suggested by balusc, now im free to use Ñs and tildes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Facelets files are been saved with the wrong character encoding. You need to to save them using UTF-8. In Eclipse, you can set that via *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*:

[image]

Edit and resave **all** templates after fixing that. Even if only one include file or master template is saved using the wrong encoding, then the whole thing would still fail.

Note that the XML prolog `<?xml ... ?>` is unnecessary. It only tells the XML parser (read: the SAX compiler of Facelets) about the version and the encoding of the saved XML file. But it defaults to UTF-8 already. You can safely get rid of them. That's also more friendly to MSIE browser.